# how to set MyEclipse color about the backgroud of tags matched

Tags: color-scheme, myeclipse

i get one MyEclipse theme ,but some i don't like.The problem is as follows.
OK,i can't upload img because no 10 reputation.And my English is poor.
problem:
      when id chose one tag in xml or html in MyEclipse,for example,I double-click the ,then the  has a background color,I want to change the color.In IntelliJ IDEA,I do this by setting>>Editor>>General>>Matched brace,then,how can i do this in MyEclipse? Help!

Comment: If you like my answer please mark it up or accept it. Thanks. http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to set the background color for highlighting matching bracket/brace/parentheses but you can alter the foreground color to something more visible than gray. Go to Preferences->Java->Editor then select the "Highlight matching brackets" entry in the list near the bottom of the preferences, then click on the color to change it. You can also play with the Bracket Highlighting options, which are seen on that preferences page.

[image: Matching brackets preferences]

Alternatively, you could try the Bracketeer eclipse plug-in. Go to Help->Install from Catalog then select the eclipse catalog (at the bottom, next to the G icon) and enter "Bracketeer" in the search box. Click the Install button for the JDT version. Look for Bracketeer preferences to try different settings; it also adds toolbar icons.

[image: Install Bracketeer]